# Show that the following number series converges, and then use euler's sum formula to approximate the sum:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show that the following number series converges, and then use euler's sum formula to approximate the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}$$

I have this 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$$
Then converges by comparison 
But i don't know if si it correct and how to do the second part of the exercise

Answer (score 1):

For the convergence itself, you already received good answers.

For the limit and the asymptotics, using partial fraction decomposition, we have
$$\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}=4\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-\left(\frac{3}{(n+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ So, considering the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}=4\sum_{n=1}^{p}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{p}\left(\frac{3}{(n+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ the first summation telescopes and it is equal to $\left(2-\frac{4}{p+2}\right)$.

Concerning the other, hoping that you know it
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}=\psi ^{(1)}(k+1)-\psi ^{(1)}(k+p+1)$$ Using the asymptotics
$$\psi ^{(1)}(k+1)-\psi ^{(1)}(k+p+1)=\psi
   ^{(1)}(k+1)-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{2k+1}{2p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$  Applying it twice we and continuing with Taylor expansion, we then have
$$S_p=\left(\frac{27}{4}-\frac{2\pi
   ^2}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this gives a quite good shortcut method for the evaluation of $S_p$.

Computing
$$S_{10}=\frac{1572379}{9604980}\approx 0.164$$ while the approximation gives
$$S_{10} \sim \frac{337}{50}-\frac{2 \pi ^2}{3} \approx 0.160$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}\leq \frac{2n+1}{(n+0)^2(n+0)^2}=\frac{2n+1}{n^4}=\frac{2}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}=\frac{1}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{4}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^4}\right)=\frac{1}{4}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^4}$$

Since both these sums converge by the p-test, we conclude the original sum converges by the comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Simply write $2n+1 = (n+2)^2 - (n+1)^2 -2$. Thus you are left with the expression $\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}= \dfrac{(n+2)-(n+1)}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}= \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}- \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)^2}$. And repeat this again. I hope you see my points...